# Str_replace - PHP - syntax error when replacing symbol

Tags: php, character, str-replace, symbols

I did a URL encode and spaces have been replaced by +.

I am trying to replace the + with %20 using str replace.

```
$x = str_replace('+', '%20', $name);
```

What is the syntax error here?

Comment: The syntax is correct.

Comment: Show us the whole file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no errors in the code you posted so your error must lie another place in your code

```
<?php
$name = "potato+tomato";
$x = str_replace('+', '%20', $name);
echo $x;
```

Output: potato%20tomato

Comment: possibly you could post it as a comment.

Comment: I fixed the error by using rawurlencode($name) instead and not using str_replace.

Comment: Somehow, url_decode and then trying to replace didn't work properly. I went straight to echo "randomtext".rawurlencode($name);

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer using the url_decode() function.

https://www.php.net/url_decode

That said, your code looks fine.